# Getting a Chinese Passport in the wrong consulate

Tags: usa, china

My wife needs a new Chinese passport and we live in Massachusetts.

On the Chinese embassy website it says "Please be advised that sending your visa application or document(s) to the incorrect office may result in complication or delay in processing or even denial of application." http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/zmzlljs/t84229.htm

As we live in Massachusetts, we are supposed to go to the NYC consulate for the passport renewal. Since my wife would need to take a day off work to go to the consulate and the fact we've been to NYC a ton of times, we would like to use the renewal as an opportunity to visit Chicago and do the passport renewal at the Chicago consulate.

Anybody have any experience on how strict the Chinese consulate enforces the location to consulate application rule?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I live in Denver, Chicago is also my designated consulate. When I tried to apply in DC, I was turned away -- they refused to accept my application outright. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

On the [website](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/fees/) it also states:

> Please submit your application to Chinese Embassy/ Consulate General
>   based on your State of residence

I don't have the experience as I have always gone to the one in my area for visas, but I would recommend to play it safe and go to the one in New York. You can always ask them once you're there if another office can process the paperwork. If you don't want to wait, just give them a call on Monday.